# In a multithreaded app, how would I use the atomic builtins to set/view a time_t value?

Tags: c++, gcc, lock-free

I have an app that is highly threaded.

The threads in this app read from a shared memory mapped file.  You can assume they never write to it.

Now what I need to do is extend it so that when a reader has finished reading from the file, it will update a shared timestamp. i.e. `time_t last_access_time = time(NULL);`

That happens so often, that I would prefer to search for a lock-free implementation if at all possible.

How would I go about setting or checking the current value of `last_access_time` using the atomic builtins in G++?

e.g. suppose I have these class members and `_last_access_time` is initialised to `time(NULL)`

```
time_t _last_access_time;

void UpdateLastAccessTime(){
     _last_access_time = time(NULL);
}

void GetLastAccessTime(){
     return _last_access_time;
}
```

Is it possible to make it lock free?

Comment: Before you go for a lock-free implementation, are you sure that you need it?  Have you tried using standard locking primitives and confirming that they are such a bottleneck that you need to optimize?

Comment: Yes I need it and I know it can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    inline
    SomeClass ()
        : m_lastAccessTime (0)
    { ; }

    inline void
    UpdateLastAccessTime ()
    {
        time_t crtTime = time (NULL);
        time_t lastTime = m_lastAccessTime;

        while (crtTime > lastTime)
        {
            lastTime = __sync_val_compare_and_swap (
                &m_lastAccessTime,
                lastTime,
                crtTime);
        }
    }

    inline time_t
    GetLastAccessTime () const
    {
         return m_lastAccessTime;
    }

private:
    volatile time_t m_lastAccessTime;
};
```

Comment: Note though that time() has only second resolution, so update will more often be a nop than do anything.